# Pointers to pointer usage giving unexpected result

Tags: c, pointers

Why is the First Printing Statement in `main()`, printing 11 ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void foo(int ** p){
    int j = 11;
    *p = &j;
    printf("%d ", **p);        //Printing 11
}

int main(){
    int i = 10;
    int *p = &i;
    foo(&p);    
    printf("%d ", *p);          //Printing 11
    printf("%d ", *p);          //Printing Random value
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Inside `foo()` , you're assigning the address of a automatic local variable `j` to `*p`. After `foo()` has finished execution, `j` does not exist anymore and thus, using (derererencing) `p` furthermore in `main()` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Now, the output of UB is, well, *undefined*.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but the thing is, why the first Printf() in main() is printing the correct value i.e. 11 ?

Comment: @ArvindRajput it _seems_ to print the _correct_ value, however there is no gurantee that it **will** print always. That's the _beauty_ of UB. :-)

Comment: @ArvindRajput: The value is probably left on the stack intact for the first call to `printf`, but then the actual `printf` call overwrites it. You can't count on that behavior, though.